# Согласование сказуемого с множеством существительных в единственном числе

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Скажите, знатоки, в каком числе должно быть сказуемое при согласовании с множеством существительное в единственном числе?

- Поле(я) "Пароль" и "Подтверждение пароля" не совпадают.

Answer (score 5):

**Поля "Пароль" и "Подтверждение пароля" не совпадают.**

Поля ― подлежащее в форме мн. числа, сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим во мн. числе.

"Пароль" и "Подтверждение пароля" ― однородные несогласованные определения, отнесенные к подлежащему.

Неогласованные определения стоят после определяемого существительного, в этом случае существительное имеет форму мн. числа.

Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа: 2. Если определяемое существительное стоит впереди определений, например: формы залогов действительного и страдательного.